# Prevent default event (browser navigation) when user clicks anchor tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table in html like below. What I want is to prevent user to direct to google.com when they click John via Javascript or Jquery. I tried it like below but it did not work. Where is my mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
           $(".myTDclass").click(function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               alert('prevented');
           });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
   <tr class="myTRClass">
    <td><a href='www.google.com' class='myTDclass'>John</a></td>
    <td>Smith</td>
   </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

onclick='false' is a solution, I know. But i need it in js or jquery. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why is your jQuery code in a `<style>` tag...? Your code will work correctly if you add it in the right place.

Comment: You're addding script in `<style>` you need to use `<script>`

Comment: sorry, syntax error while writing the question here only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues here. Firstly your jQuery code is, for some unknown reason, in a `style` tag when it should be in a `script` tag. Secondly, you haven't included jQuery in the page at all. Lastly the code itself needs to be in a document.ready event handler if you place it in the `head` of the document.

Once you fix those issues it should work fine. Try this:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function() {
           $(".myTDclass").click(function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();
               alert('prevented');
           });
        });
    </script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed my code as you suggested. The code on the question is edited. Still not working somehow? Can u please check?

Comment: It should be working fine given the code you've shown. Check the console for errors.

Comment: I did. No error I see and I am redirected to C:\Users\emel\Desktop\www.google.com

Comment: yes, working good there. What should be my problem here. Did ctrl+f5 to clear cache, same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't really help you without seeing an example of the problem.

Comment: That looks like a security issue as you're running on the local file system. You need to run on a webserver to avoid that... 'feature' of IE. Or better yet, forget IE exists and use something else.